# wordpress child theme add to the_content overwriting instead

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a child theme using the wordpress 2013 template.

I want to add some content after the_content() so I have made a filter like this:

```
function bluebaronhomepage(){   
    $content .= '<h1>hello from extra content</h1>';
    return $content;
}....

add_filter('the_content', 'bluebaronhomepage');
```

This is overwriting the content from the page and just showing the 'hello....'. I was hoping it would append the content with the hello at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter should take `$content` as a parameter:

```
function bluebaronhomepage($content){   
    $content .= '<h1>hello from extra content</h1>';
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'bluebaronhomepage');
```

In the code you posted, `$content` is undefined and then you set it to `<h1>...`. When you return that string you overwrite all of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass by argument the content to your filter:

```
function bluebaronhomepage($content = ''){   
  $content .= '<h1>hello from extra content</h1>';
  return $content;
}....

add_filter('the_content', 'bluebaronhomepage');
```

You have more info about this filter at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)